# What's the meaning "to put something from someone's mind"?

Tags: meaning

I searched the online dictionaries but I didn't find any definition about the phrase  below:

> I put the issue from my mind.

So could you please tell me what the meaning of it is?

The fuller text is here:

> I asked about a memory. It was from the weeks before I’d left for BYU,
>   after Shawn had had a particularly bad night. He’d brought Mother to tears,
>   then plopped onto the sofa and turned on the TV. I’d found her sobbing at
>   the kitchen table, and she’d asked me not to go to BYU. “You’re the only
>   one strong enough to handle him,” she’d said. “I can’t, and your father
>   can’t. It has to be you.”
>   I typed slowly, reluctantly: Do you remember telling me not to go toschool, that I was the only one who could handle Shawn?
>   Yes, I remember that.
>   There was a pause, then more words appeared—words I hadn’t known I
>   needed to hear, but once I saw them, I realized I’d been searching my
>   whole life for them.
>   You were my child. I should have protected you.
>   I lived a lifetime in the moment I read those lines, a life that was not the
>   one I had actually lived. I became a different person, who remembered a
>   different childhood. I didn’t understand the magic of those words then, and
>   I don’t understand it now. I know only this: that when my mother told me
>   she had not been the mother to me that she wished she’d been, she became
>   that mother for the first time.
>   I love you, I wrote, and closed my laptop.
>   —MOTHER AND I SPOKE only once about that conversation, on the phone, a
>   week later. “It’s being dealt with,” she said. “I told your father what you and
>   your sister said. Shawn will get help.”
>   **I put the issue from my mind**. My mother had taken up the cause. She
>   was strong. She had built that business, with all those people working for
>   her, and it dwarfed my father’s business, and all the other businesses in the
>   whole town; she, that docile woman, had a power in her the rest of us
>   couldn’t contemplate. And Dad. He had changed. He was softer, more
>   prone to laugh. The future could be different from the past. Even the past
>   could be different from the past, because my memories could change: I no
>   longer remembered Mother listening in the kitchen while Shawn pinned
>   me to the floor, pressing my windpipe. I no longer remembered her looking
>   away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasal verb "put from" means "not to keep". To put a topic or issue from one's mind is to stop thinking about, worrying about, or concentrating on that thing. The narrator had been worried about the issue of help for Shawn, but was told by her mother that this was being arranged. Thus she was able to stop worrying about it.